# cmd error "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, cmd.exe

I am getting this error when I am doing a cd into a directory I stored in environment variables.

But the thing is, when I cd into the same directory using the same ev using vim, I can successfully cd into that directory.

This is true for all the directories stored in ev, even the $HOME path.

Please help me out.

The environment variable is setup like this:

Name: dev Value: E:\Software Development

Command: cd $dev
or cd $HOME
or cd $TMP

Non of the commands are working.
But in vim,
:cd $dev does the job.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Did you edit the path in the System- or User-level environment variables?  Are you sure you're running in the same user scope for both the command-prompt as you are with Vim?  IE: Does Vim run "as administrator" by any chance, and/or are you opening the command prompt "as administrator"?

Comment: I am running both without administrator privileges.
I have added the custom path to user level, and I just tried the System-level $TMP and even it doesn't work (have tried both cmd and cmder), but again in vim $TMP and all other ev seem to work.

Comment: How exactly are you modifying the environment variables?

Comment: Through Advanced System Setting dialog.

Comment: Bizarre, well based on what you're provided it should just work.  There must be a piece missing from your info someplace...

Comment: I hope there is not, I am extremely frustrated, have to write the full path all the time.
Everything was working fine a week ago.

Comment: Have you tried using a system restore point to go back to when it was working?

Comment: That is the last resort, I hope I can work it out without that, and I really thought it's a common problem :|

Comment: [If you **show people the _exact_ commands that you told the computer to run** rather than expect them to guess](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html), then you'll probably find this cleared up in short order.

Comment: Edited to add specific commands and link to image to show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I told you that this would be quick once you asked the question properly.

You state that you are running

```
cd $TMP
```

in Microsoft's command interpreter, `cmd`.

That is not the syntax used for environment variable expansion in Microsoft's command interpreter.  The syntax is

```
cd %TMP%
```

.  Yes, the trailing percent sign is important.

Comment: It seems like user3224858 is confusing cmd with powershell but it is strange anyway :o

Comment: Oh darn. It is working, but still, I can cd into ev that I have set myself, that is I can cd into HOME using:
cd %HOME%
but cd %dev% is not changing the directory and just keeping me in the current directory without giving any error.